# Time complexity difference between hash_table[key] == NULL and hash_table.find(key) == hash_table.end()?

Tags: c++, hashmap

I am currently writing a trie tree, and wondering that if there is any time complexity difference between

hash_table[key] == NULL

and

hash_table.find(key) == hash_table.end()

if key is not in the table. the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) says the time complexity of map::find is log(n)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not equivalent; the first will insert `key` into the map if it's not already present.

Comment: `std::map` is a binary tree, not a hash map. You probably meant `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, user657267

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Oliver Charlesworth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity is the same in both cases, but if all you want to do is check for absence in a map that apparently has a `mapped_type` that is a pointer and for which `nullptr` is an invalid value, the first form will be strictly slower because in the case of absence it will first *insert* a new value into the map for `key`. So that's extra work you have to do... which is best-case only valid under pretty rigid circumstances.

If all you want to do is test for the presence of a value, just do either:

```
if (map.find(key) == map.end()) {
    // absent
}
```

or

```
if (!map.count(key)) {

}
```

Comment: Not quite the same: lookup is constant time, insert is amortized co stant, worst case O(n), I believe.  These are not the same.

Comment: @Yakk Lookup can be worst-case O(n) too.

Comment: Also if you're inserting and looking up at the same time, if you didn't find it, you already know exactly where to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches do entirely different things:

- `hash_table[key]` inserts an element for `key` with a default constructed value
- `hash_table.find(key)` merely locates the element with the `key` in the `hash_table` and returns `end()` if it isn't found

In both cases, the complexity for a a `hash_table` is actually expected to be amortized constant. That is, from a complexity point of view there isn't any difference but inserting the elements may have an unnecessary cost (it depends on whether the `key` is inserted anyway; if so, keeping a reference could make it more efficient).

If `hash_table` happens to be a `std::map<K, V>` rather than an `std::unordered_map<K, V>` the complexity of both operations is `O(log n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the container. Since using the subscript operator inserts the element, the `n` may be bigger: it probably won't change the complexity (unless a lot more keys are tried than keys are present) but the performance of using `find()` is likely to be better.